# Changing the color of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flash, colors

I need to change the color of an image on a website. The image is of a carport, so the texture and shadow's needs to stay consistent. If I change the color by just swapping the images with other ones in a different color I would have to have approximately 7500 images and I don't think it would be the most efficient way of doing this, so I am asking the community if there is a jQuery code that would allow me to place some sort of color filter on top of a white carport and change the color real-time on the website?

This is a sample of one of the images I have to start with.
[image]

The only thing that can change color is the roof part, the metal rails in the image cannot change color and the background cannot change color either.

Update: I think it would be easier to make this using flash. I know that car dealer sites use flash as well. Does anyone know any good tutorials for flash?

Comment: What about simply overlaying it with a partially transparent div, with a background color and opacity?

Comment: what about creating a flash app instead of jquery or javascript?

Comment: Please don't go to that trouble w/o checking this out. I've got an example of what I mean here. Basically, you take the carport image and you use GIMP to do the following: convert color to alpha channel - this "bleeds" the white out and leaves you with semi-transparent areas inside the carport. Then change the background around it to be solid white. Then whatever color you have in the dive behind it bleeds in and you just change the div. [Your carport here](http://hcc-fargo.com/carport)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use php to generate the image, with the [imagecopymerge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) function. It would save time being able to set the color filter and image in the url:

```
<img src="image.php?img=carport&color=blue" />
```

Comment: Your example and source links are broken, thus rendering this answer useless.

Answer (score 6):

Can you create the "colorless" image as something like a PNG which supports transparency and then have a colored div or something in the background that bleeds through?

Comment: But how do you change the image of the background without affecting the background around the image?

Comment: Give the covering div a background image which is completely transparent in the 'background' areas, and has a semi-transparent color where your object is.  This still means making individual images for each color, but once you have a mask it may be easy enough to do automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Put a transparent div over your image and change it's background accordingly.
In the example link below, I used jQuery to change colors when button is clicked.  I used several CSS transparency properties so you get a cross browser solution.

Opacity properties for cross browser compatibility including IE6

```
.opacity{
    -khtml-opacity:.20;
    -moz-opacity:.20;
    -ms-filter:”alpha(opacity=20)”;
    filter:alpha(opacity=20);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.2);
    opacity:.20;
}
```

jQuery code, when button is clicked color changes.

```
$('#red, #green, #yellow, #blue').click(function(e) {
    var x = e.target.id;
    $('.filter').css({'background': x})
})
```

### Check working example with at http://jsfiddle.net/gVQc3/4/

Answer (score 0):

Given html like the following:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1157/1054046043_82c48223f1.jpg" />
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
<ul id="colors">
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Green</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#gallery img {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.4em;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
    left: 0.5em;
    right: 0.5em;
    bottom: 0.5em;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

#colors:before {
    content: "Select a color overlay: ";
}

#colors li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
$('#colors li').hover(
    function(){
        var color = $(this).text();
        $('#overlay').css('background-color',color);
    },
    function(){
        $('#overlay').css('background-color','transparent');
    });
```

[Leads to the following JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PAtTs/).